# Windows Explorer Jumplist delay

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, jumplist

I've begun to have an issue with the Jump list for Windows Explorer (Windows 7). What happens is that when i gesture click, or right click on the explorer icon the first time after rebooting the initial menu (Windows Explorer, Unpin) and the Jump List with my pinned folders and frequent folders works fine.

Any subsequent attempt will open the initial menu, but the jump list will experience a long delay (10-20 seconds) before the pinned and frequent folders will pop up.

Initially my frequent folders would grab a networked drive which I thought might be the cause. I have removed that from the list and there is still no change.

I really enjoy being able to quickly hit directories i use often and this is quite frustrating. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your Explorer jumplist, which will probably have the side-effect of speeding up its access, even if it does mean you have to recreate it. To reset it, go to the folder:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
```

and delete this file:

```
1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms
```

That file corresponds to Explorer's jump list; deleting other files in the folder will clear other programs' jump lists. The changes should take effect immediately. If not, restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been running Windows 10 Pro x64, and have been experiencing Jumplist delay of about 1-2 sec when trying to open jumplist folders from Windows Explorer Taskbar Icon. After hours of researching and testing, I discovered that my issue was caused by two Explorer Context Menu Items (GDContextMenu64.dll) added by Google’s Backup and Sync app.

I used CCleaner (Free) to disable these two context menu items:

*Directory GDContextMenu
*Drive GDContextMenu64

Then I relaunched explorer.exe, and NO MORE JUMPLIST DELAY!!! 

See image below.  In CCleaner, you can navigate to TOOLS, and select the CONTEXT MENU tab to access and enable/disable the Explorer context menu items.

[Screenshot of CCleaner Context Menu Editor Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvYzx.png)